# Nested Port Forward

Tags: port-forwarding

Is there a built in software way to essentially port forward like the following?

```
example.com/81/* -> example.com:81/*
example.com/82/* -> example.com:82/*
...
```

Alternatively maybe for subdomains something similar?

```
example.com/a/* -> a.example.com/*
example.com/b/* -> b.example.com/*
...
```

I understand there may be speed issues but I would like to essentially access all ports on my machine when only being able to open one port through my router.

I believe I can feasible get this to work with pipes with node.js but this seems like it may be a common need.

EDIT: I like I stated only have one port to work with for communication with a computer.  Its behind a firewall.  Besides sshing into the machine I would like an easy way to access the other ports on the server(only 1 port to access) that isn't very intensive.

Comment: Since it appears telcoM's answer isn't what you're looking for, could you go back a few steps and explain what problem you're trying to solve? Right now, it seems you've come up with a solution and either are struggling to explain it to us and/or it isn't technically possible, and thus we've been unable to help. But if you go back a few steps, explain the higher-level problem you're aiming to solve, I think that'd help us to understand the goal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, that's not really *port forwarding* but *HTTP reverse proxying* (with some URI manipulation added), and that would only be applicable for HTTP-speaking services.

In your first example:

```
example.com/81/* -> example.com:81/*
```

the client would have to connect to `example.com:80` and then send out a syntactically valid HTTP request (e.g. a GET request) for an URI that matches `/81/*`, and then the reverse proxy would connect on client's behalf to `example.com:81`, and re-submit the request, modified by deleting the initial `/81` from it.

If you attempted to connect to e.g. an IMAP mail service in example.com:143 in this way, the mail client would have to, instead of just connecting to the target address and port,  connect to port 80 on the target and send a message like this:

```
CONNECT example.com:143 HTTP/1.1
```

...and then continue using the standard IMAP protocol.

No standard mail client I know of has such a feature, although it would be technically possible to implement it. Also, the CONNECT method of HTTP is security-sensitive and its use should be strictly controlled: unrestricted HTTP proxies that allow CONNECT are easy targets for abuse.

Comment: A port/url identifier can return whatever protocol it would like I thought.  It just a port/path so I'm not sure why http speaking services would only be relevant.  If it makes more sense expand the port client side on the users machine.  `127.0.0.1:81 -> example.com/81/* -> example.com:81/*`

Comment: You're correct that specifying the hostname/IP:port part is protocol-agnostic in the sense you're thinking of, but the URI part is not. Specifying the `/81/*` part to the server requires communicating with the port, which requires the use of a protocol in the same way as speaking requires the use of a language. "Expand the port client side" sounds like you're looking for a HTTP tunneling solution like [chisel](https://github.com/jpillora/chisel).